# DIV cover/overlap other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a reusable function that enable me to easily cover or overlap an element such as select, textfield, input, div, table and etc with a semitransparent div to it's exact height and width.

I am able to get the element position and size:

```
$(element).height()
$(element).width()
$(element).offset().top
$(element).offset().left
```

However, how can I bind the element position and size with the div? If the element position or size change, so as the div will change. Any suggestion that how I can do it? Or, is there any existing jquery plugin for this? I believe this will be very useful for temporary disable an element from user interaction for operation such as ajax and etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function/plugin using the jQuery `.wrap()` function and the appropriate CSS for the overlay..

```
$.fn.overlay = function() {

    return this.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);

      var left = $this.offset().left;
      var top = $this.offset().top;
      var width = $this.outerWidth();
      var height = $this.outerHeight();

      $this.wrap("<div id='overlay'> </div>")
        .css('opacity', '0.2')
        .css('z-index', '2')
        .css('background','gray');
    });
};
```

Demo on Bootply: **http://bootply.com/87132**

This should work generically and be reusable.. not just for Bootstrap elements!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VebVq/)**

**css**

```
div {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
height:200px;
width:400px; 
background-color:green;
}

div div {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.5;
}

div div input {
position:relative;
top:25px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond. But I am seeking for an reusable solution. I mean having a div that will automatically detect the size of element that I want to overlap and also the position of that element. Then, place that div on top of that element.